# Proper implementation of numerically integrated function inside a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, numerics, implementation-details

I have a numerically-inverted function `TP` which is then fed to the differential equation below. My question is: What is the right way to implement this `TP` if I want to obtain a series solution of the differential equation in $t$? The only necessary boundary condition is that `g` must vanish at infinity. Do I need to series expand `TP` and then insert to the differential equation? Or is it just ok to plug-in `TP` itself into the differential equation?

Thank you.

BTW, $q$ can take values $-\infty<q<1$ while $b>0$ and $\infty<\rho<\infty$.

```
 rho[r_, b_, q_] := (2 b/(1 - q)) (1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]
 TP = Rationalize[InverseFunction[Function[{r, b, q}, rho[r, b, q]], 1, 3]] (*dr/dρ*)
 dTP[ρ_, b_, q_] := (Sqrt[1 - (b/TP)^(1 - q)] ((b/T)^(1 - q))^(1/(1 - q)) TP)/b 
 odeρ = 2 TP dTP[ρ, b, q] g'[ρ] + (TP)^2 g''[ρ] -l (l +1) g[ρ] // Simplify
 odey = odeρ /. g -> (g[#/b] &) /. ρ -> b y // Simplify
 odet = odey /. g -> (g[1/#] &) /. y -> 1/t // Simplify
 odetSeries = Series[odet /. g -> Function[{t}, t^p Sum[a[i] t^i, {i, 0,7}]] // Simplify, {t, 0, 4}] // Simplify
```

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish what you ask for but a first step would be to really use `TP` as a _function_ and provide arguments to it, e.g. `TP[ρ, b, q]`.

Comment: I already answered this question and gave the code. Why don't you use my code?

Comment: Hi @AlexTrounev. I used your code but I cannot reproduce a specific case in my problem.

Comment: @user583893 What is a special case?